# Get location of element you just pushed into vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am curious about how pushing back into a vector works. I want a way to push back an element and then be able to add it's location in the vector to a double array serving as a type of map.

Something like this:

```
// Create a bomb
Bomb b;
b.currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
b.explodeTime = SDL_GetTicks() + 3000;
b.owner = player;
b.power = 2;    
b.x = x;
b.y = y;

bombVec.push_back(b);

bombs[y][x] = THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT;
```

This way when I explode the bomb, I can check the map and then have an ID in the vector to deal with. Every non bomb square will have a -1. Also, just curious. Imagine I have 3 elements in a vector. I delete the second one and then add another. Does the new element go in the same location as the one that was deleted?

Thanks!

Comment: Deleting from a vector is not a good idea. It requires all the elements to be shifted. And no, it will not be inserted where the other was deleted, but always in the end of the array. You might want to take a look at `list`

Comment: @StevenBurnap, that is the iterator to the last element, not the last element itself. `*bombVec.rbegin()` or otherwise `bombVec.back()` would be the last element. Using its index would be `bombVec[bombVec.size()-1]`

Comment: Of course you can delete from vectors...there's nothing wrong with that.  It would be a pretty useless data type if you could never remove anything from them!  Now if you're working on an algorithm that needs to be very efficient, making a bunch of add/delete calls to a vector is a bad idea...because yes, deleting requires other elements to be shifted.  But there's absolutely nothing wrong with deleting an object from a vector.

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13879484/2932052) has more answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you `push_back`, you can use `back` to get the element.

```
Bomb b;
...
bombVec.push_back(b);
Bomb &bref = bombVec.back();
```

Or do you want the index?

**Obligatory warning:** If you push another item in, and the capacity isn't large enough, the vector will be resized.  This will invalidate the reference and will cause program errors if the reference is accessed.  This isn't a problem with (1) accessing by index (2) if pointers are stored in the `vector` (3) if you use `list` instead (4) if you don't resize the `vector`.

**Getting the index:**

```
size_t index = bombVec.size();
bombVec.push_back(b);
```

Comment: I need the index. Thanks! And yes, I will ensure the vector will never be resized. If I reserve 15 elements and although more than 15 elements are created but not more than 10 at a time, does this still prevent resizing?

Comment: Yes, that will prevent resizing.

Comment: Obligatory warning (extended): The reference can also become *invalid* if elements are `erase`d from the vector and basically whenever an operation *modifies* the container.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas What about the index?

Comment: If you modify the vector, the index may refer to a different object or an unallocated slot and thus become invalid. If you want to store a smart pointer to an object, do that. If you want to access them by some kind of fixed index, then assign them a fixed index and use a map.

Comment: It's kind of frustrating answering C++ questions, because some people aren't satisfied unless you enumerate *every* possible circumstance under which a reference becomes invalid.  For chris's sake, people, I'm not going to copy/paste the entire `std::vector` documentation into every answer.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The reason for bringing this up is that the question explicitly mentions removal of elements from the container. That is, there is good reason to consider the `erase` operation --not all operations, but at the very least those that are mentioned in the question (Admittedly the question talks about *deleting* an element from the vector, I can only assume that he means *erasing*)

Comment: @DietrichEpp: `some people aren't satisfied unless you enumerate every possible circumstance` That's what I like about the C++ community, they are very thorough :).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the end:

> Also, just curious. Imagine I have 3 elements in a vector. I delete the second one and then add another. Does the new element go in the same location as the one that was deleted?

Delete has a precise meaning in the language, which makes no sense in this context, so I will assume that you mean *erase* from the container. When you *erase* an element from a vector, all elements with indices greater than the erased element are *moved* (or copied) filling in the empty space left by the erased element. If you `push_back` a new element that element will be added to the *back* of the container, so it will not take the same location.

Another option is not *erasing* the original element but writing the new element over the location where the older element is: `v[ idx ] = new_value;`. Which brings us to the first part of the question:

> I want a way to push back an element and then be able to add it's location in the vector to a double array serving as a type of map

The problem with using a vector as the underlying container is that any mutating operation on the container invalidates iterators and references to the stored elements. For example, the `erase` above will invalidate iterators and pointers to all elements with greater indices (technically it invalidates *all* iterators according to the standard, but in practice....). Adding elements to the container can be even worse as it can actually invalidate *all* iterators/references if the vector needs to grow.

A common suggested alternative is keeping indices to the location of the element. While indices are stable if the container grows, they will refer to the wrong location if you *erase* from the container, so you will need to be careful on how you operate. If you can manage not to remove elements from the vector (for example adding a flag that marks a bomb as removed but not actually remove it from the container) then the problem becomes much simpler.