# Get index of object inserted into a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, std

How can I get the position where my object was actually inserted?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<SomeClass> list;
SomeClass object;
list.push_back(object);

list[...].method(); // I do not have the key
```

Unfortunately `push_back` does not return anything since its return type is `void`.

Comment: As an unrelated hint, don't ever use 'list' as the name for a variable, especially not for a variable of type 'vector'.  'list' is also a container in the standard library.  Having a vector named list is going  to be a continual source of grief for anyone who has to read this code.

Comment: I changed the name of your class from `class` (which is invalid C++) into `SomeClass` and added [a thought about the idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40740375/2932052) behind the seemingly "trivial behaviour".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If `v` is your vector, the following will give you the position (that is, the index):

```
v.push_back(object);
size_t pos = v.size() - 1;
```

Or you can look at the `size()` before calling `push_back()`. Then you won't need to subtract one.

Comment: Thanks for both your answer and the hint to look at the size before inserting.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/) member to obtain a reference to the last element:

```
list.push_back(object);
list.back();
```

Or, since push_back() simply adds the object to the end, the index of the newly-inserted element is the vector size minus one:

```
list.push_back(object);
vector<my_class>::size_type object_pos = list.size() - 1;
```

Comment: I assume that gives an iterator pointing to the last inserted element? That moment I am more interested in the index as an integer that in the object itself.

Comment: @sharethis No, back() returns a reference. To get the index of the inserted element, compute the new vector size and subtract one.

Comment: Similarly, `&v.back()-&v.front()` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to locate a particular element after you have them, and you don't want to save the index ahead of time (in case you do something to the vector like sort/add/remove/etc), you could also use the [find algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

Comment: Well, you know how many elements you have inserted so you can find the index much easier (and much more efficient) than by using `find`.

Comment: I'm saying if you need to find some key after the elements have been inserted, and you didn't already save out the index you want, this might work. Just another tool to be considered depending on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While [NPE's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879499/2932052) shows a pragmatic POV, I concentrate on the **reasoning** for this simple answer. The observable behaviour is [just the purpose of the `push_back` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.

So the index is always equal to `v.size()` before insertion or, equivalently, `v.size()-1` after insertion. If this assertion cannot been fulfilled, the capacity of the container could not be grown or your class throws an exception in the copy/move constructor (see section [Exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back#Exceptions) in the documentation).